# Why Is My Jquery Slide div always showing at the start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery slide toggle but I want hit the div on start up but it is always showing

Here is a demo I build to show u what I mean.

Maybe you can see where I am going wrong

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
 
<style> 
#panel,#flip
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:Red;
border:solid 5px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
padding:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">This div should always be hidden til clicked </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the panel div

this should do it

```
#panel
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @GoreDefex I flagged your comment, it was childish

Comment: @Jamessavage thanks :) I definately wasn't the abused one here at all. good times.

Comment: @GoreDefex When I said I flagged a comment i meant your  abusive one about wanting to downvote him once you hit 125 rep, u child

Comment: Clearly u missed that users comments on my answer + that users downvoting of my answer because it had "extra jquuery" which to that... which to that user meant it deserved some downvoting... thats ridiculous..

Comment: Also. The comment that u just commented on, was 100% sarcasm & frusteration... SO is supposed to be a place to post multiple answers to a question... whatever.

Comment: @GoreDefex I missed nothing this guy mery gave his opinion and voted on your answer which he has every right to do, u then turned around and attacked him and post on his question cant wait to donwvote it, that is just childish u kid so grow up and if i could i would downvte ur answer because it offers no informationa and is just a pointless amount of extra querys, when this guy did it on two words

Comment: Sure. U know all, clearly... That's how SO works is it? Its not a community of people trying to all fill answers to questions for people landing on recent google searches to thing asked 1000 times... is it... so theres clearly no value in trying to show someone two different jquery approaches to change their code by one line... i only did one line of code different than the poster... I showed two diff states... I showed how one line placed just before the code posted here could have allowed it to work. How does that deserve losing rep? How does that = whst SO is all about?

Comment: Seems to me your the one attacking me... i didnt go anywhere near as far as your taking this...

Comment: @GoreDefex I am merly defending this guy he gave me and clear response and merly drop a comment on your answer and again has the very right to vote on it, BUT u then turned around and out right attacked him to u not see how stupid u sound saying people are attacking you when u attacked first

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //just need an initial run to close it first
    $("#panel").slideDown();

    //or if it was open to start use this instead
    $("#panel").slideUp();


    //rest the same
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```